# how to duplicate a webdriver in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, web-crawler

I am doing some Web Scraping using selenium webdriver. The issue is that i need to go to lots of subpages(from main page) to scrape data. Instead of going back to main page, I want to make a duplicate of the driver when it is on main page. Something like `driver_sub = driver.copy()`.
Then I can go to subpage using *driver_sub* and run `driver_sub.quit()` to end. Is it possible?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'copy'

Answer (score 1):

Open the sub pages in tab and then close the tabs respectively via webdriver, also make your webdriver static , so as to share the same copy among all the pages

Comment: is right , driver just a instance of particular browser it is not page specific.only way to handle this by opening every page in new tab and then accessing them by driver.windowHandles()

Answer (score 0):

you can use drivers.WindowHandles.ToList() to store all subpages then you can use that list to perform actions as required on the pages.